# Using JSON to update a custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have a custom post type, lets call it products. When a user drags this product to the shopping cart (droppable jQuery UI), I want the key called "amount" in my custom post type to reduce by one.

So far I have a JSON function via jQuery $.ajax that looks like this:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://localhost:8888/MAMP/nogg/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/functions.php',
    data: { postid: +id },
    type: 'post',
    success: function(output) {
        alert("amount is reduced by 1.");
    }
});
```

This send the id of the post to functions.php, then I use this to get the data in my functions.php

```
if(isset($_POST['postid']) && !empty($_POST['postid'])) {
    $postid = $_POST['postid'];
    $response = json_decode($postid);
    remove_amount($response);
}
```

Which calls the function with the postid.

```
function remove_amount($postid) {
    $amount = get_post_meta($postid, 'amount', true);
    update_post_meta($postid, 'amount', $amount--);
}
```

This gives me a 500 error, I've made sure it's the correct ID that has been sent, and checked the name of the field containing the key (amount).

So what is my dumb self missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to `json_decode` the `$_POST['postid']` variable.

The [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method serializes your data object and sends the data in your request header just like a regular `POST`.  jQuery isn't sending JSON to your server.  (You could change your ajax parameters to actually send JSON, but I wouldn't complicate your life over a wordpress install.  The way you are using `$.ajax` is fine.)

Try it like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['postid']) && !empty($_POST['postid'])) {
    // Make sure you do something in this function to prevent SQL injection.
    remove_amount($_POST['postid']);
}
```

Also, what's with the `+id` in your data object?  Is that intentional?  Other than that you'll need to give us the PHP error that is causing the HTTP 500.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I just threw it in there as a last ditch effort before coming over here. It doesn't work either way. Thanks for the answer tho, cleared up when and why to use json_decode! :)

Comment: Ah yes! I can check the php_error.log for details, totally spaced out there. The error log says:   PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_post_meta() in /Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp/nogg/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/functions.php on line 706                 which totally boggles my mind. Is there perhaps something in functions.php that hinders it from handling the json? Should I try to load a new .php file with the function instead?

Answer (score 0):

get_post_meta returns a string if you've set the $single param to true, which you have.

So, is your error related to trying to decrement a string value?

What about casting your amount val to an int before decrementing it?

```
function remove_amount($postid) {
    (int)$amount = get_post_meta($postid, 'amount', true);
    update_post_meta($postid, 'amount', $amount--);
}
```

Does the line of the error message you are getting (706) correspond to the line where you are handling your update meta?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it. Apparently there's something in the WP functions file that doesn't approve of handling json content like that. Hence not recognizing the standard WP-functions (like get_post_meta), what I did was to create a blank page, had it use a custom template with the php code, then in the jquery code I linked to that WP-page.

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://localhost:8888/MAMP/nogg/wordpress/?page_id=43',
               data: {postid2: id },
               type: 'post',
               success: function(output) {
      }
});
```

and page_id=43 is a page using the template below:

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: ajax template
* Description: ajax *
* @package WordPress
*/


if(isset($_POST['postid']) && !empty($_POST['postid'])) {
remove_amount($_POST['postid']);
}

function remove_amount($postid) {
$amount = get_post_meta($postid, 'amount', true);
if($amount > 0):
    update_post_meta($postid, 'amount', $amount-1);
    echo $amount-1;
endif;
}
```

Now the code runs as it should, now I just need to do what Stephen said and add some sql-injection protection. Thanks for the answers! Got me in the right direction!